# Images appear in Flutter Android AAB analysis after being deleted

Tags: android, flutter, caching

Google recently introduced a 150MB limit for AAB uploads to Play Store. We had an AAB that was over 200MB. To reduce our AAB size, I replaced all of our images' asset references (raw file) to network assets. Then, after running `flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm --analyze-size` and analysing the output JSON file (`.flutter-devtools/aab-code-size-analysis.json`), I can see a bunch of entries for images in `Assets` that I previously deleted. Why are these there and is there a way to clear those from impacting an AAB build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I deleted everything in the `android/app/build` folder then built the app again with: `flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm --analyze-size` and can see that the changes I made with images (network references v. local references) resulted in nearly 80MB saved with the .aab size!

Comment: Couldn't you also do `flutter clean`? Weirdly, this is not [documented on flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/reference/flutter-cli), but `flutter --help` shows it. It seems to clean the Xcode files, not sure about Android.